# href not allowing me to click on urls

Tags: hyperref, href

I am writing a research paper. The goal of this project is to simply add a link to the project. I've added

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
```

The paragraph that I am working on is written like so:

```
We developed many word matching exercises in our computer 
science courses to enable students to match the key terms 
with their descriptions. Figure \ref{fig:fig1} shows an 
example of a word matching exercise, which can be viewed from 
\href{https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/wordmatch/Section1_2.html}{https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/wordmatch/Section1_2.html}
```

Expected:
I should be able to click on the link and visit the website.

Actual:
Nothing happens when I click on the link.

Any help with this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/wordmatch/Section1_2.html}{https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/wordmatch/Section1_2.html}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please supply a small but complete test file (don't you get an error from the `_` I get an error if I try to make a complete document from your fragment.

Comment: I added an example document, after any error the PDF is not intended to be usable. If you do not get an error please edit the document to show what definitions you are using. (The error can be avoided by using `\_` for `_`  or by using `\url{...}` rather than `\href`

Comment: apart from the error with the `_` it should work. Which viewer do you use? And can you show your log-file?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan making a URL string clickable, I can see no reason for not using `\url{...}` instead of `\href{...}{...}`. If you absolutely must use `\href` to display the URL string, be sure to encase its second argument in a `\url` wrapper.

Oh, and do load the `xurl` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xurl}
\urlstyle{same} % optional
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\url{https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/wordmatch/Section1_2.html}

\href{https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/wordmatch/Section1_2.html}{\url{https://liveexample.pearsoncmg.com/wordmatch/Section1_2.html}}
\end{document}
```